# Update mysql.user from non-root yet privileged account?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

This question might sound silly, but I wanted to make absolutely certain before I carried this out on a production MySQL instance.

Currently, I have a `MySQL` master->slave setup on a production environment.

Our DBA has since left the company and no one is aware of the `root` password. This has not been a huge deal as before he left he gave me (not a DBA) an account on the `MySQL` instance with full permissions, we have carried out most of the required "root" tasks via this (my) account.

However, recently the master->slave replication has broken and I would like to follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o#3229580

Requiring me to change the root password to something I actually know.

My question is: Logged in as my escalated user, is there any detrimental effect to changing the root password via `update mysql.user` short of the possibility of breaking replication? Will this work or does `MySQL` need to be in `safe-mode` to make changed to the root account?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step by step instructions to reset the MySQL root password from [their manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html):

> 1. Stop the MySQL server if necessary, then restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges, and disables account-management
>      statements such as ALTER USER and SET PASSWORD. Because this is
>      insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction
>      with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.
> 2. Connect to the MySQL server using the mysql client; no password is necessary because the server was started with --skip-grant-tables:
>
>    `shell> mysql`
> 3. In the mysql client, tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work:
>
>    `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
>
>    Then change the 'root'@'localhost' account password. Replace the password with the password that you want to use. To change the
>      password for a root account with a different host name part, modify
>      the instructions to use that host name.
>
>    `mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

Comment: I'm not asking how to change the root password, I can do that fine. I am asking if I can do it from an account that has permissions as I do not wish to stop the server.

Comment: @HydraIO:  From MySQL, run `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';` and if you get an error, it means you have to follow my answer.

Comment: If your user has a `WITH GRANT OPTION` then you may be able to edit the root user password without needing a restart. `set password for 'root' = password('newpass')`

Comment: If stopping the server to fix the access is inconvenient then maybe you should consider stopping the server to implement proper high availability (master-master or multi-master replication)

Answer (score 0):

run 'SHOW GRANTS FOR [your user]@[hostname you connect from];'

That will show you what permissions you have.

From that you can work out if you can change the root password within your session as opposed to doing a 'cold' reset of the password.

The safest way is to use the 'ALTER USER' command mentioned before, the show grants will indicate if you have permission to (or just try it, it can only error)